# Discord.py: on_member_join suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, discord.py

I have the following code that I am trying out:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("works")
    for channel in member.guild.text_channels:
        if channel.name == 'general':
            await channel.send("Welcome to " + member.guild.name + ", " + member + "!")
```

My previous `on_member_join` event worked fine, but for some reason it doesn't anymore. I have tried updating to discord.py 1.5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting no errors.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, I have no errors

Comment: Do you have `on_command_error` event for error handling and are you sure the channel exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`discord.py` 1.5.0 now supports discord API's Privileged Gateway Intents. In order to be able to exploit server data, you need to:

- Enable `Presence Intent` and `Server Members Intent` in your [discord application](https://discord.com/developers/applications):

[image]

- Use [`discord.Intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents) at the beginning of your code:

```py
intents = Intents.all()

#If you use commands.Bot()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

#If you use discord.Client()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```