# Discord.py on_raw_reaction_remove member not found (remove role on reaction remove)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I get a *member not found* error when trying to remove a role on reaction remove (on_raw_reaction_remove).

It works to add the role to the member, but it can't remove the role afterwards.

My guess is that it can't properly get the ID for the member, but I don't really know how to fix it.

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == xxxx:  #ID depends on message
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'xxx':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="xxx")
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'xxxx':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="xxx")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = payload.emoji.name)
        
        if role is not None: 
            member = payload.member
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("member not found")
        else:
            print("role not found.")

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == xxxx:  #ID depends on message
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'wexxed':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="xxxx")
        elif payload.emoji.name == 'xxxx':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="xxx")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = payload.emoji.name)
        
        if role is not None:
            member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("member not found")
        else:
            print("role not found.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`payload.member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.member) only works with [`on_raw_reaction_add()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add), so, instead of using it, you have to fetch the user:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    (...)
```

PS: If you have `discord.py` 1.5.0 and didn't set up your `Intents`, you should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410314/discord-py-on-member-join-suddenly-stopped-working/64412428#64412428), or else, your events won't work right.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have exactly this code and added the discord.Intent.all(). Nevertheless, I can access the guild but not the guild.members

Comment: Have you activated Intents in your discord app?

Comment: I have already solved, I had to substitude de get(guild.members, ...) to member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)