# guild.members not working correctly discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get a list of members in a server using `discord.py`

My code is:

```
@client.command()
async def members(ctx):
    
    members = ctx.guild.members

    for member in members:

        await ctx.send(member.name)

    await ctx.send("done")
```

But the problem is it's sending the name of the bot only. If you figure out what's the problem in the code then can you pls help me, I want the name of all members.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py: on\_member\_join suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410314/discord-py-on-member-join-suddenly-stopped-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'll give you a brief answer, so that you can understand very well.

> intents are as same as permissions, in a way

**so what is their use?**
intents are required if you wanna get certain events happening in server.
some can be enabled just by the script, and some intents like **presence** and **members**
require going to discord developer portal and manually enabling **+** enabling in script

so you just open your script and go to top, add these lines:

```
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, members=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('prefix_here'), intents=intents)
```

it is using commands, but you can also use this with the `discord.client` method too, which can be done by..

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

now you try to run your script **with these** :)

Comment: For me, it shows an error: `NameError: name 'discord' is not defined` when I try what you did. I'm using bot commands.

Comment: Since there is not much information given, I can guess that the issue in your case should be that you forgot `import discord`, please read up on [name errors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) and in what all situations they are thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Intents` for your bot, modify your code to use this and it should solve the issue.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

[More information on intents.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)