# Why I can't see all the members in the list guild.members?

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    Guild = client.get_guild(000000000000000000)
    msg = message.content.lower() # message
    user = message.author # normal user that sent the message

    if msg.startswith('.mute'):
        if has_role('Admin', user):
            userID = msg[9:-1] # Takes the ID
            userID = int(userID)
            member = None
            for k in range(len(Guild.members)):
              if Guild.members[k].id == userID:
                member = Guild.members[k]

            if member is not None and has_role('Muted', user) == False:
                await member.add_roles(Guild.get_role(000000000000000000))
```

I wanted to implement a small function in my discord bot.
If you write ".mute @mentionuser" the bot should take the ID of the member mentioned (and this work), then he should look in the list of the members of the server if there is a member, whose ID is equal to the ID of the member mentioned. The guild found from `client.get_guild()` is right.
The problem is that `Guild.members` returns a list that contains only the bot itself, so the result is `member = None` every time that I search someone that is not the bot itself.
I even tried to use the `get_member()` [function](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) but with the same result

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [guild.members not working correctly discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524256/guild-members-not-working-correctly-discord-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire list of members is sensitive information, so it is not shown to bots by default. You have to enable it (and other "privileged intents") in your bot configuration, and if your bot is in more than 100 guilds then it will require your bot to be verified and whitelisted. [Read more](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412).

Once you've enabled this in your bot configuration, you also need to supply the appropriate [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.members) to your client.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
# rest of your code...
```