# how to get specific info from audit logs discord py

Tags: discord.py

I need audit logs to give me info on name changes only not all all the logs. This is the current code I'm using. You can modify it to only read the certain logs

```
async def save_audit_logs(guild):
 with open(f'audit_logs_{guild.name}', 'w+') as f:
      async for entry in guild.audit_logs(limit=100):
           f.write('{0.user} did {0.action} to {0.target}'.format(entry))

@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('audit'):
        await save_audit_logs(message.channel.guild)
```

Comment: my bot can record it own name change but it wont record if someone changes someone else name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`on_member_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update) to do this :

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    channel = get(before.guild.text_channels, name='log channel name')
    if before.display_name != after.display_name:
        await channel.send(f'{before.mention} changed named')
```

If you want to know who changed the user's name :

```py
entry = list(await after.guild.audit_logs(limit=1).flatten())[0]
user = entry.user
```

If you want to access the old and the new name :

```
prev_name = before.display_name
cur_name = after.display_name
```

Comment: its a good soliton but it only logs when someone changes the bots username i want to log all name changes

Comment: It will log every name changes, not only the bot's one :) If it's not the case, you didn't [enabled Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410314/discord-py-on-member-join-suddenly-stopped-working/64412428#64412428)