# Discord.py (Rewrite) on_member_update not working properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a question about the on_member_update function of the discord.py package.
My Issue is that the on_member_update function only triggers when the bot itself is updated (like a role update) and not when an other user is updated (how it's supposed to work).
Here is a breakdown of my Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sys


TOKEN = 'myToken'
BOT_PREFIX = '!'



Intents = discord.Intents()
Intents.members = True
Intents.presences = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, Intents = Intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(before.status) == "online":
        if str(after.status) == "offline":
            print("{} has gone {}.".format(after.name,after.status))
    else:
        print("lol")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def stop(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send("bot stopped")
    sys.exit(0)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Hope you  have an idea how to make it work.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You probably don't have your Intents enabled. Here's how you can [enable them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410314/discord-py-on-member-join-suddenly-stopped-working/64412428#64412428) if it's the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the presences intents for your bot from the developers portal like in the image below.

[discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAn8m.png

Comment: It was already activated on my side - on_member_update doesn't trigger after migrating from discord.py to nextcord

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me.

I needed to change:

**on_member_update** to **on_presence_update** according to the migration guide:

https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating_2.html

"***on_presence_update()*** replaces ***on_member_update()*** for updates to Member.status and Member.activities."