# I would like to make a discord bot that sends a message when a member goes online but I can't seem to make it work ? (python)

Tags: python, events, discord, discord.py

I would like to make it so when a member goes online my both will send a message in the server welcoming the member but I cannot find a way to do so if I could get the name of the user too it would help thank you.
[Here is my code that is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ctV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Even though your code snippet is not too long, it would be better to type the code into your question. In doing so, you allow the community to copy-paste your code for experimentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that currently works

```py
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if after.status.name == 'online':
        await client.get_channel(id=`channel_id`).send('Hello')

client.run(`your_token`)
```

[on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update)

> Called when a Member updates their profile.
>
> This is called when one or more of the following things change:
>
> - status
> - activity
> - nickname
> - roles
> - pending
>
> **This requires Intents.members to be enabled.**

You also need to [allow presences](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.presences) to do what you really want

> Whether guild presence related events are enabled.
>
> This corresponds to the following events:
>
> - on_member_update() (activities, **status**)

[And finally do what this answer mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64845993/11972800)

Comment: Thanks, this worked do I need to make an other variable for commands now ?

Comment: never mind I got it just got to client = command.Bot(command_prefix = '', intents=intents)