# Using get_member() function doesn't return a member

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm relatively new to discord.py and I'm having some trouble get a user id and turning it into a member object. I already know about using 'member: discord.Member' to get a member object, but I don't want this. For some reason whenever I run the following code, I always get a None return, I've ran this code with my own userId hardcoded in. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@commands.command()
async def master(self, ctx, *args):
    member = ctx.guild.get_member(userId)
    print(member) # This always prints out none
    masterDoc = db.collection(u'master').document(str(member.id))
```

Comment: Have you [setup your Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64412428/12874027) correctly ?

Comment: I just found about intents. Thank you though. Do you know anything about setting up intents for a heroku server?

Comment: You just have to enable them on your discord app and add the code sample in your code. There's no additionnal steps to make it work on heroku.