# Discord.py leaderboard command not working

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

Ok, so i'm making a discord bot, and it does "Pathetic Leveling".
I'm having trouble with a leaderboard command, for some reason the code below only returns the bot in embed. Help, please?

```
@lvl.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(ctx.guild.id)
    for member in guild.members:
        path = pather(ctx.guild.id, member.id, "pathetic.txt", 0)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Pathetic Leaderboard for " + ctx.guild.name, color=colors.dark_magenta)

        with open(path + "pathetic.txt", "r") as file:
            patheticness = file.read()
            embed.add_field(name=member.name, value=f"Pathetic Lvl: {patheticness}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The output looks like an embed with:

```
Pathetic Leaderboard for CodeFriends
Pathetic
Pathetic Lvl: 0
```

Comment: Hey @SaberCodeBoy welcome, could you include some examples of the output you're seeing as well as try to clarify what you mean by 'only returns the bot in embed'

Comment: @AndyReifman sure, essentially it outputs an embed with the title and only one field, which is called "Pathetic" and has the value of 0.

Comment: Is your issue that it's sending an embedded message, or that the embedded message does not contain all the information it should have? Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Have you enabled your intents ? If not, you can watch [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410314/discord-py-on-member-join-suddenly-stopped-working/64412428#64412428).